# How to get a value from a dialog when on any thread?

Tags: java, codenameone, event-dispatch-thread

I wonder if this is the right way for getting a PIN from a dialog?

```
public static <T> T getFromGui(Supplier<T> supplier) {
    if (CN.isEdt()) return supplier.get();
    final Object[] holder = new Object[1];
    CN.callSeriallyAndWait(() -> holder[0] = supplier.get());
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") final T result = (T) holder[0];
    return result;
}

public static String askPin() {
    if (!CN.isEdt()) return getFromGui(() -> askPin(bankzugang));

    ...
    final boolean cont = Dialog.show(
        "Your PIN", BoxLayout.encloseY(pin, label), ok, cancel) == ok;
    return cont? pin.getText() : "";
}
```

It seems to work (tried once), but I'm a bit confused about `callSeriallyAndWait`: Is it the analogon of `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait`? What are the differences?

Actually, I need a few dialogs to work from every thread, including EDT. Is there a better way than adding the "getFromGui" line to each of them as above?

Comment: Invoking UI code on a separate thread is an EDT violation (https://www.codenameone.com/manual/edt.html#_debugging_edt_violations), you cannot do that without the risk of a crash. If you are in separate thread and you want to show a `Dialog`, then that `Dialog` should be called inside a `callSeriallyAndWait`. Modal `Dialog`s (the default) block the current EDT thread until the `Dialog` is dismissed, using `invokeAndBlock` under the hood. For an explanation, see: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/edt.html#invoke-And-Block-section

Comment: @FrancescoGalgani But I am calling `callSeriallyAndWait`, aren't I? I may be doing it wrong - that's why I'm asking, but the call is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `callSeriallyAndWait` is the equivalent of `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait`. There's no logical difference.

This can work but there's a couple of concerns here... First:

What if two threads show a dialog like that at once. The first will dispose to show the second dialog which might dispose to show the first dialog in an infinite loop... This can happen even if your physically on the EDT because the code isn't a part of the normal application flow.

Unlike Swing we have only one `Form` at a time so a dialog "goes back" and that can get tricky.

So first of all your GUI code needs to check that you're not currently asking for a pin and the best way to do that is to have one class responsible for getting the pin from the user if necessary and it should have a static state. If should also check that there's no other dialog showing at this time and if so it might want to avoid showing e.g.:

```
if(getCurrentForm() instanceof Dialog) {
   // ... don't show yet
}
```

If I understand your problem correctly you have background threads that might need a pin. In that case more than one thread might be caught without a pin and would need it from the GUI. So both threads need to be suspended but only one of them should invoke `callSeriallyAndWait`... This means the current approach is sub par anyway.

Normally we avoid `callSeriallyAndWait` as it's much slower (on Swing too). I would also use an `InteractionDialog` or similar which is less intrusive than a regular dialog. However, it isn't modal. But in this case it shouldn't matter.

You need to develop your own thread blocking code for the background threads and it can react to a standard callback to release all the waiting background threads. You can then just use any code you want to create the GUI and use any listener then update shared state in the class with the new pin and invoke `notifyAll()` to wake up threads waiting for the pin. E.g.

```
synchronized(LOCK) {
     if(pin == null && !dialogIsShowing) {
         dialogIsShowing = true;
         callSerially(() -> promptForPin());
     }
     while(pin == null) {
         LOCK.wait();
     }
}
```

Then the UI logic:

```
private void onUserSubmittedPin(String pin) {
     synchronized(LOCK) {
         this.pin = pin;
         dialogIsShowing = false;
         LOCK.notifyAll();
     }
}
```

Comment: You indeed understood my problem correctly, thank you for the long answer. I could reproduce the problem of multiple threads. While the user is entering a PIN, another dialog popped up. It worked well per se, but it's a terrible UX indeed. However, now I have even more questions, see my next comment.

Comment: How should the infinite loop be possible? Despite `getFromGui` being recursive, it calls itself at most once.
`+++` Avoiding `callSeriallyAndWait` as it's much slower. The user needs about one second for the input, so what time scale are we speaking about?
`+++` Concerning "`if (getCurrentForm() instanceof Dialog)` don't show yet", can it be done smarter than sleeping and rechecking in a busy loop?

Comment: You're on a separate thread so it's OK to wait. There is no need to give a time limit as you would use the `wait`/`notifyAll` calls which will only wake up when a pin is submitted. The loop is there "just to be safe" but would work more like an `if` statement. Once a dialog is shown the EDT wakes up and the call to getFromGUI will happen again. You need to guard against that by turning on a flag such as `isDialogShowing` and effectively put the thread into `wait()` state without showing the second dialog in that case. I'll try to edit the answer to clarify.

Comment: I guess, that's about the endless recursion, but the calling `askPin` on a non-EDT thread invokes `getFromGUI` on the EDT thread, which returns `supplier.get()` on the first line, which invokes `askPin` directly (i.e., still on the EDT thread), and the condition on the first line is false, so it proceeds to the normal execution. `+++` Put differently, a non-EDT thread calls into EDT and EDT processes normally. There's no more inter-thread interaction (except for the result passing  after the dialog is gone). `+++` IOW the supplier gets passed to the EDT and stays there.

Comment: See [my demo](https://github.com/Maaartinus/pinDialogs/blob/master/src/bugs/demo/BugForm1.java) written before I read your update.

Comment: Notify/wait is a more powerful approach here. Notice that I hold the synchronized lock in both cases and so access to the variables is inherently thread safe. When I enter `wait()` I release the lock and can't wake up until it's available. This is far more efficient than timed wait and less error prone.