# Advantages of InteractionDialog over Dialog?

Tags: java, codenameone, event-dispatch-thread

I was [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58360011/581205) to use `InteractionDialog` rather than `Dialog`, but I'm failing to see the advantages. What I can see is a problem. What I need is letting the user enter a PIN or whatever and wait for their answer. This is needed both on the EDT thread (the user choose to save the PIN) and on other threads (a web page requires the PIN for login).

With `Dialog`,

- I can call it from the EDT thread and it works nice.
- When on a different thread, I can be trivially adapted by a one-liner in the callee (see `getFromGui` in my linked question).

With `InteractionDialog`,

- I can use it easily from other threads via some simple `wait`/`notifyAll` magic.
- I can't use it from the EDT thread, except via callbacks like `okBtn.addActionListener(...)`, which is verbose and ugly.

---

So I am confused and asking:

- *What do I gain from the `InteractionDialog`?*
- *Is there a simple way how to use it uniformly no matter what thread I am on?*

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59122720/581205) for how I deal with forms in place of modal dialogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate things here:

- Modality
- How it works

A dialog can be modal or non-modal but it isn't interactive like an `InteractionDialog`. The modal dialog blocks the EDT internally using `InvokeAndBlock` so the current thread stops until there's a response from the dialog. This is convenient but has some edge case issues. E.g. the event that launched the dialog might trigger other events that would happen after the dialog was dismissed and cause odd behavior.

But that's not the big thing in modality. Modality effectively means the form behind you "doesn't exist". Everything that matters is the content of the dialog and until that is finished we don't care about the form behind. This core idea meant that a dialog effectively derives form and as such it behaves exactly like showing another form effectively disabling the current form. What you see behind the dialog is a drawing of the previous form, not the actual form.

Text fields can pose a problem. Because the way the dialog is positioned (effectively padded into place within its form using margin) the UI can't be scrolled as text field requires when the virtual keyboard rises. Since people use dialogs in such scenarios we try to workaround most of these problems but sometimes it's very hard e.g. if the dialog has a lot of top margin, the virtual keyboard is open and covering it. Or if the user rotates the screen at which point the margin positioning the dialog becomes invalid.

Note that in `InteractionDialog` Some of these issues such as the margin to position also apply.

Now `InteractionDialog` is a completely different beast that sprung out of a completely different use case. What if we want a dialog such as a "color palette that floats on top of the ui?

We can move it from one place to another but still interact with the underlying form. That's the core use case for `InteractionDialog`. As such modality is no longer something we need so it was never baked into `InteractionDialog` although it technically could have been (but it doesn't make sense to the core use case).

It's implemented as a `Container` placed into the layered pane of the current form so the form around it is real. Because the form is "live" layout works better and the removal of modality makes some edge cases related to editing slightly better. There are still some inherent problems with dialog positioning and rotation though. It also allows you to click outside of the dialog while input is ongoing which might be a desirable/undesirable effect for your use case.

Overall I try to use dialogs only for very simple cases and avoid input when possible. If I use input I never use more than one field (e.g. no-username and password fields) so I won't need to scroll. These things work badly for native UIs as well e.g. with the virtual keyboard obscuring the submit button etc. Since those behaviors are very hard to get right for all resolution/virtual keyboard scenarios.

Comment: Interacting with the underlying form makes usually no sense for my use scenarios, as the question must be answered before doing anything else (in some cases, it could wait, but there's a timeout). Unfortunately, my "dialogs" need quite a few fields (or a single field with multi-line additional information). So I guess, I have to pop up a form "modally", i.e., hide the menu, disable the back button and so on.

Comment: You can also use a form instead of a dialog and give it the design elements of a dialog by placing the content in a centered container with the dialog UIID.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now. It's not perfect and it forces me to call the "dialog" differently, depending on whether I'm on the EDT or not (shown in my self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from Shai, I wrote a form working as the base class for most of my dialogs. Basically, it shows the content from the subclass and adds the "OK" and "Cancel" buttons.

There's a method for use from the EDT thread like

```
public void showAndThen(BooleanConsumer consumer) {
    assert CN.isEdt();

    ...
    okBtn.addActionListener(a -> {
        lastForm.show();
        consumer.accept(true);
    });
    cancelBtn.addActionListener(a -> {
        lastForm.showBack();
        consumer.accept(false);
    });
}
```

where `BooleanConsumer` is a trivial `void accept(boolean b)` interface.

There's another method for use from other threads

```
@Override public final boolean ask() {
    assert !CN.isEdt();
    final BooleanTransfer transfer = new BooleanTransfer();
    CN.callSerially(() -> showAndThen(result -> transfer.set(result)));
    return transfer.await();
}
```

where `BooleanTransfer` is a two-method class where the thread calling `set` passes a `boolean` to the thread calling `await`.